# Relation between $\mathbf{P}(X \geq t)$ and $\mathbf{P}(g(X) \geq t)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

For any positive, non-decreasing function $g$, what can we say about the two probabilities

$ P(\mathbf{X}\geq t)$  and $P(g(\mathbf{X}) \geq t)$  ?

Is it true that

$ P(\mathbf{X}\geq t)  \geq P(g(\mathbf{X}) \geq t)$.

I am aware of the inequality $ P(\mathbf{X}\geq t)  \leq P(g(\mathbf{X}) \geq g(t))$.  But this inequality applies $g$ to both sides of $t$.

Comment: Think about the cases $g(t)=t^2$ and $g(t)=\sqrt{t}$. It depends on $g$ and $t$. Nothing more can be said without more information. For that matter, consider $g(t)=kt$ for $k<1$ or $k>1$.

Comment: @MPW, for $g(x) = |x|^q$ for $q \geq 1$ does the inequality $P(\mathbf{X}\geq t)  \geq P(g(\mathbf{X}) \geq t)$ holds ?

Comment: Not necessarily. Suppose $t > 1$, $q > 1$ and $\mathbf{X}$ is positive with probability 1. Then $t^{1/q} < t$, so

$$P(\mathbf{X}\geq t) < P(\mathbf{X}\geq t^{1/q}) = P(g(\mathbf{X}) \geq t).$$

We can get the reverse inequality if $t \in (0,1)$ and the other assumptions remain the same.

In general, if \(g\) is strictly increasing on the support of $\mathbf{X}$, the inequality is dictated by the relationship between $t$ and $g^{-1}(t)$. For general $g$, you need to look at the probability of $\left\{\mathbf{X} \in g^{-1}\left([t,\infty)\right)\right\}$.

Comment: I made a slight mistake. For the inequality to be strict, $\mathbf{X}$ has to have positive probability of being in the interval $[t^{1/q},t)$. A nice sufficient condition for this is that $\mathbf{X}$ has positive density on the positive reals. For example, $\mathbf{X}$ might be exponentially distributed.